# About expansive homeomorphism on a compact metric space

Tags: dynamical-systems

Let $X$ be a compact infinte metric space and $f:X\to X$ an expansive homeomorphism. (Mapping $f:X\to X$ is expansive if $(\exists \epsilon >0)(\forall x\neq y)(\exists n\in \mathbb{Z}) d(f^n(x),f^n(y)) > \epsilon$ or, equivalent: $(\exists \epsilon >0)((\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}) d(f^n(x),f^n(y)) \leq \epsilon \implies x=y)$.) Prove that there are 2 different points $x,y\in X$ such that $lim_{n\to \infty} d(f^n(x),f^n(y))=0$.

My idea was: there must exist a point that isn't a fixed point (because otherwise $f$ would be identity and that isn't expansive). We observe that point $x$ and point $y=f(x)$.

$lim_{n\to \infty} d(f^n(x),f^n(y))=\\
lim_{n\to \infty} d(f^n(x),f^{n+1}(x))=\\
d(lim_{n\to \infty}f^n(x),lim_{n\to \infty} f^{n+1}(x))=\\
d(lim_{n\to \infty}f^n(x),lim_{n\to \infty} f^n(x))=0$

But I'm not sure that this calculation is correct.

Comment: The identity on a finite compact metric space is expansive, and the claim does not hold for that

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry, the definition I've given is wrong, I'll edit it now.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Do you know if this solution holds for infinite spaces? Because that would mean a lot too.

Comment: @blue the third line is false, because you don't know that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} f^n(x)$ exists (and indeed there is no reason that it should exist)

Comment: I don't see any essential difference to before the edit - in particular, the identity on a finite space is still expansive.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I agree, the condition that $X$ is infinite is essential and the whole statement doesn't hold if it is finite and identity is an example for that. However, I still need the solution for the infinite case :D

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki That's what troubled me too. I haven't used the fact that $f$ is homeomorphism, maybe it has something to do with that? If $f^n(x)$ doesn't converge, then it has countable number of convergent subsequences. Is that strange or not?

Comment: Is it on purpose that negative $n$ is allowed in the definition of expansive?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Well yes. If we restrict to $n\in \mathbb{N}$, that's called positive expansive and there is a theorem that states that if $f$ is positive expansive homeomorphism, then $X$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

You know $f$ is not positive expansive, which implies there exist $x\neq y$ and $0<\delta<\epsilon$ such that $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))\leq \delta$ for all $n\geq 0$ (you can take $\delta=\epsilon/2$). If the quantity$$L:=\limsup_{n\to\infty} d(f^n(x),f^n(y))$$ is zero, we're done. Otherwise, pick a sequence $n_k$ such that $\lim d(f^{n_k}(x),f^{n_k}(y))=L$ and such that $f^{n_k}(x)\to x^*$ and $f^{n_k}(y)\to y^*$ for some $x^*,y^*.$ We necessarily have $d(x^*,y^*)=L,$ so $x^*\neq y^*.$ For any $r\in\mathbb Z,$
$$d(f^r(x^*),f^r(y^*))=\lim_{k\to\infty} d(f^{r+n_k}(x),f^{r+n_k}(y))\leq\delta,$$ which contradicts expansivity of $f.$